# Ionic sass custom sheets

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass

I have some problems with SASS in ionic,
Whats the problem?
The problem is that custom stylesheet's doesn't work how it should.

I have sass folder with ionic.app.scss file and _test.scss file with some code.
I imported _test.css in ionic.app.scss file like this:

```
@import "../scss/test";
```

And when I edit and save ionic.app.scss, it's works perfectly, compiled in min.css and working in my browser, but when I edit and save my _test.scss file, nothing happening. _test.scss file only works, when I compile my ionic.app.scss file.

Can someone help me with that? What I miss??

Comment: Can you show us some code? Gulpfile, Iconic version, cordova versions etc?

Comment: Ionic v - 1.7.15
`
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var sh = require('shelljs');

var paths = {
  sass: ['./scss/**/*.scss']
};

gulp.task('default', ['sass']);

gulp.task('sass', function(done) {
  gulp.src('./scss/ionic.app.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .on('error', sass.logError)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'))
    .pipe(minifyCss({
      keepSpecialComments: 0
    }))
    .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.css' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'))
    .on('end', done);
});
`

Comment: // Include all of Ionic
[eta]import "www/lib/ionic/scss/ionic"; 
  
[eta]import "www/lib/ionic/scss/test";

Comment: Why have you tagged Less? It seems to be a Sass specific problem. Please don't tag Less when it is not applicable.

Comment: @Andrius could you edit your post and include your gulpfile there? Its pretty hard to understand when its in a comment. Theres an edit button under your question. Can you also show your folder structure for .scss files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I'm assuming you are using Ionic 1.x.x in my answer. You have a couple of places where you should check.

First is the `ionic.project` file:

```
"watchPatterns": [
  "www/**/*",
  "!www/lib/**/*"
]
```

Make sure you have your directory inside the `watchPatterns`. This most probably is correct since it's the Ionic default. You however mentioned `sass` folder in your question so I can't be sure. This is why I'm suggesting all the custom folder stuff below. **Although** you also mentioned that `ionic.app.scss` is located in the same folder so the folder probably is the default ionic folder if you have not changed the name of the folder.

Secondly in your `gulpfile.js` you have the following:

```
sass: [
  './scss/**/*.scss',
  './www/customfolder/**/*.scss'
],
```

Make sure your css file is included in these paths. The second one is a possibility when a custom folder is used. Just set the path correctly. This will then use the default ionic gulp task `sass` and watcher `watch`.

After this you should be able to include your custom SASS stylesheet in the `scss/ionic.app.scss` file (not in www folder) with the following:

```
@import "www/customdirectory/style"; // If custom directory

/* IN YOUR CASE */

@import "style";
```

If the _style.scss file is in the same directory as the ionic.app.scss then you do not need to set the path, just the name of the file is enough.

Hopefully this can be helpful to you when trying to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your folder structure, It's a shot in the dark but i think your `_test.scss` file isnt being watched.

Try moving it to be in the same directory as the other files and change your import to be.

```
@import "{folderName}/test";
```

Just make sure its within the scss folder with the other files